# How can I move MkMapView.userLocation on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I want to make an application that will need userLocation, but MkMapView.userLocation is just readonly, can't be change. how can I use it? can I setting userLocation like
myMap.userLocation=MyCurrentLocation;

any code I need to make it easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **CLLocationManager** to get the current location of the user updated. The **locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:** method of **CLLocationManagerDelegate** will update you the current user location.

You may follow [this tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) to learn to implement it.

Comment: in other word, you can't fake your location.